# Indicate label can be tapped to expand (iOS)

Tags: ios, flat-design

I have a flat iOS design for a simple hangman-style game.  At the top, there is a label telling how many games have been won in the current session.  When clicked, it expands to a page showing detailed stats such as total wins, streaks, etc.  How do I show the user that the label can be tapped?

Comment: Show us a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the count in a round button with suitable background color and let the numbers keep updating after winning every game. Users will tap on it anyway:

[image]